# Updating a spinner when SQLite is updated

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I have an application where a user can enter in a EditText field an artist's name and it will be added to the sqlite table. That works great, but I also have a spinner on the same activity/layout that I want to update with these new changes. Here's how I have it setup:

I have a sqlite class that will insert the new name and method that will query the table and return an 'ArtistList' array.

In my activity, I'm able to get the ArtistList into the spinner using an Array Adapter when first created.

The user enters a new name in the EditText, updates the sqlite table, success...

I tried to reload the ArrayList and ArrayAdapter by running the sqlite method ArtistList but the spinner  still doesn't update, it still has the same old list before the update. I know I can just doa  artistList.add(), but that will make the list out of order. I would like to have this list in Alphabetical order which is why I'm retrieving the ArrayList from the sqlite class, the sqlite is organizing the data for me.

I tried using setNotifyOnChange, I tried a new (and clearing) arraylist and adapter...nothing is working.

This is ran onCreate:

```
sqlclass helper = new sqlclass(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        artistList = helper.getArtistList(db, tableName);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, artistList);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

Thanks for your help!

**Nevermind...**
I ended up making a new adapter...and added spinner.setAdapter(adapter). Not sure if that was supposed to be there because the spinner was displaying find until the update, but it's working now...

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for this being vague but look into using a CursorAdapter ... I think it will allow you to re-query and update the data set.

Comment: Are you saying to use a CursorAdapter in my sqlite? I'm researching this in google, because I'm not understanding that. Is that CursorAdapter supposed to help me create the ArrayList? Because I'm able to get the updated arraylist just fine, its just the spinner is not updating.

Comment: I apologize, I punched that answer in quickly and didn't have much to back it up ... If you're using the array adapter, are you keeping a reference to the List<T> that is your data set and replacing it? If so, turn off the setNotifyOnChange(true) (set to false), use clear, then addAll() with the new dataset, then call notifyDataSetChanged()

Used to have to do stuff like this with DataAdapters under swing with the Model setup they had.

Again I apologize for my vague response initially.